# How to delete the old image in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

how To delete physically old image after updating

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Job job, HttpPostedFileBase jobimage)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),job.JobImage));
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), jobimage.FileName);
        jobimage.SaveAs(path);
        job.JobImage = jobimage.FileName;
        db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName", job.CategoryId);
    return View(job);
}
```

this line  :

> System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),job.JobImage));

not working any help and thank u

Comment: `this line not working` What about it isn't working?

Comment: i need to delete my old image in my server .
Because I no longer need it .

Comment: @ElMehdiElMellali ASP.NET MVC is a web framework. It has nothing to do with database access. The code you posted looks like Entity Framework. There are a lot of tutorials that show how to delete records. If this *isn't* related to EF, don't post EF code at all

Comment: In any case `how to delete old image` doesn't explain anything. Are you asking how to delete the *file* stored in `Uploads`? What does `not working` mean? What does the *path* look like? Store it in a variable before calling `Delete` and check it. Most likely it's wrong

Comment: What is the value of `job.JobImage`? If it isn't what you are expecting, you need to lookup the `Job` from Entity Framework rather than using `job`.

Comment: @ElMehdiElMellali what is the *actual* problem? Is an exception thrown? What is its message and *full* text, as returned by Exception.ToString()?

Comment: Does the file really exist? Does the `Delete`-call throw an Exception, if so which Exception? What is the type of `job.JobImage`, is it a **`string`**?

Comment: If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

Comment: What is `Job` and what is the type of `JobImage`? Unless it's a string that contains a path name a) the problem is obvious and b) we can't really help. Is `Job` a custom class in your code? Does it come from a third-party library? What are its properties? Does it contain any file-related properties ?

Comment: job is table in database and class 
type of the jobimage is string
System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),job.JobImage)); job.jobImage Where this value "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper" Not Name of image

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i wanna to delete the file stored in Uploads?

Comment: @ElMehdiElMellali that was understood the first time you posted it. Don't repeat that comment. And that string you posted is the name of a type, which means that is NOT an image or a file. It's a class derived from HttpPostedFileWrapper. That class has properties. One of the is FileName. Use *that* property, not the root object itself.

Comment: @ElMehdiElMellali on the other hand, if due to a bug `Job.JobImage` is a string with only a type name, there's a bug in the code that stores jobs. You can't recover the original image's path because it was never stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add this line :**

> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobImage)

**in your view for example :**

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

file delete take string path
Please take look at the sample code

```
 // Delete a file by using File class static method...
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\DeleteTest\test.txt"))
        {
            // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to
            // handle the case of the file already being
            // opened by another process.
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Public\DeleteTest\test.txt");
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The OP already *Path.Combine()*-s a Path with a Filename, so I think this answer adds very little.

Comment: System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),job.JobImage)); 
job.jobImage Where this value "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper" Not Name of image

Comment: @ElMehdiElMellali that is the name of a type, not a file name. Unless you mean that you tried to use an *object* as if it were a string and got the type name instead?